# How can I configure sublime to always open to the same folder?

Tags: json, sublimetext3, config

I have a folder that I want Sublime to always open to ...

```
my_folder
```

Is there somewhere I can set this so that when ever I click on the Sublime Icon it opens to this folder?

For some reason if I manually quit sublime text through the menu it will open my last folder on re-opening.

However, if I just click the close X button, it will not ... it will open a blank window.

Is there somewhere I can set this correctly in the JSON file?

Comment: Closing the window is not the same as quitting Sublime, particularly on MacOS where applications run in the background with no windows. In such a case closing the window keeps Sublime running, and clicking the dock icon creates a new empty window as if you just launched Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure if you are aware of it, but ST has a quick switch project (usually ctrl+alt+p) that will show you your recently opened projects.
Of course it has its own drawbacks:

Unable to remove one instance from it without removing all (clear recent projects cache)Can’t open the project in a new window… instead it only replaces the current project

But AFAIK this would be the most optimal way to work with multiple projects. you just need to go to the folder of the desired project and open it once and it will be available as recent project in the future…

The point of having to choose where to save the project file, IMO is because you may want to share the same file with other people or just have them wherever you want… maybe having all in one place is good for you (it is for me as well) but other people might like to have it in separate folders.

I usually work with the project replace window… or just go in “Project -> Open recent -> …” which opens a new ST window for me!

Hope this helps you